# Make a check mark appear when colorbox is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've added colorbox to a site that contains product attributes. When a user has selected the attributes and closed the popup I either want to change the background colour of the button used to open the popup, or display a marker so that they know they have chosen the options for that product out of the grid layout.

I have got a close event firing ok on colorbox. I tested it with alert("closed"), so i know that it is activating correctly.

So i added:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
         document.getElementById('.inline').style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
});
```

but it didn't change the background colour of the "inline" class.

What am i doing wrong?
If i decide to go with a check mark that is hidden with display:none; what is the process for overriding the display:none; css?

Thanks

Comment: You can't access the class with `document.getElementById(`. use `document.querySelectorAll('.inline')`

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple problems I see here:

A. You're incorrectly accessing a class name "by id".  Switch to jQuery CSS selector and css() method to change the BG color:

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
    $('.inline').css({backgroundColor: "#f3f3f3"});
});
```

B. You may want to add your event listener directly in the colorbox options in the constructor, rather than on the document, which ought to perform better, and will kill the listener when the colorbox is destroyed (no memory leaks):

```
$('#my_colorbox').colorbox({
    // options
    onClosed: function() {
        $('.inline').css({backgroundColor: "#f3f3f3"});
    }
});
```

Comment: Your answer gave the correct result as far as changing the background colour is concerned, but it made me see a shortfall in the idea. It makes the buttons on all the products go that colour. Somehow I need to pass a unique identifier when the close is clicked. Each button has a unique id in the first place, for example .button26
Not sure if i can somehow pass this as a hidden field into the popup, and then return it when it's closed. jQuery is my weakest point so it won't be easy for me, but I'll have a go.

Comment: @StevePrice - Try putting an id attribute on the close-button, e.g. `<button id="close_button" class="inline">` and reference it with `$('#close_button').css(...)` instead.  That will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the class with `document.getElementById()`. Use `document.querySelectorAll('.inline')` instead.

or use jquery way

```
$('.inline').css('backgroundColor', '#f3f3f3');
```

Use

```
$(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
        document.querySelectorAll('.inline').style.backgroundColor = "#f3f3f3";
});
```